# Why does image has larger size?

Tags: android, layout

I'm using such layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

The `drawable/logo.xml`:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/login_logo"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

The `drawable/login_logo.png` has 280 pixels width, my Galaxy Tab screen width is 600px but in launched app I see the image takes almost all screen width and it is about 500px

Where did I make mistake?

**SOLVED**
By setting

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

and putting image to `drawable-hdpi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your picture in background, and the `android:background` tag uses 9 patch images. So your background always stretches to the width and height of the view. Your layout width is set to `fill_parent`, so the image width is `fill_parent` too.
The solution could be to make a 9 patch image of the png you are using with `.9.png` extension.
Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) for [drawing 9 patch images](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) - developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Did you put the points at correct location? I mean if you want to convert the whole image as non-strechable you need to put points at both length and width

Comment: Yea, I've added necessary stretch-zones.. but the problem is device zooms every image it works with

Comment: Are you putting minimum sdk version and target sdk version in your Android-manifest.xml? If not put minimum sdk version 3 and target sdk version 4 atleast.

Comment: Yes, already found by myself. As it turned out min SDK version = 4 is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. As you are saying it is for galaxy tab so it is coming under drawable-hdpi.So change the resolution of image with photoshop or something and put it inside drawable-hdpi.
2. and try to use **android:layout_width="wrap_content"**. instead of **android:layout_width="fil_parent"**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you have a good read of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). If you have placed your image in the drawable-mdpi folder, then in high density screens the image will appear to be 1.5x in size. You will have to provide different resolutions of your image for different screen densities.

Comment: I also tried to put the same image in `drawable-hdpi` but there was the same effect.